# How can i retrieve data from hashmap as it is , without removing escape char in java

Tags: java, hashmap

Escape char removed while reading from hashmap

```
import java.util.*;
// our main class becomes a file but the main method is still found
public class HelloWorld
{

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1,"hai");
  map.put(2,"h\"ai");
Iterator entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
String value =(String) entry.getValue();
System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
}
}
}

 Output:  Key = 1, Value = hai
          Key = 2, Value = h"ai
 Expected: Key = 1, Value = hai
          Key = 2, Value = h\"ai
```

It's not about data printing , i mean same status should get when pull the value from map. I did debugging
i am able to see correct data in map. when i performed getValue it's output string dont have "\" char.

Note: It' not about printing data if we print  System.out.println("hahs\"dk");
it will give  hahs"dk . I am worry about runtime value

Please some can help on this or suggest some link.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe use `"hahs\\\"dk"`. That will make it `"hahs\"dk"`

Comment: I cant change data. data send by client.
When client send data to server , it's able to catch into hashmap properly.
but while reading form it i am losseing it

Comment: Then get the data as String and use `data.replace("\"", "\\\"")`

Comment: there is no such thing as "while reading form it i am losseing it ".    if the client sends a backslash, and it gets into the map, then you also get it when you get the string from the map. what you show us is your debug values which are incorrect.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi, Java can handle a String with backslash properly. if the client indeed sends a string with backslash, there is no need to "escape" it